# How to send date when submitting a form with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, forms

I followed this [tutorial](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) where I can make a form where user submits a comment and name. However, I want to send the date the user presses the submit-button. It seems like it only saves data that user puts into the textfields. I don't want the users to be able do it themselves. How do I do it?

I was using jQuery but changed to Node.js / Express because I had to save the data to a database, and I don't understand it very well.

Code on index.ejs:

```
  <form action="/tweets" method="POST">
 <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="name" name="name">
 <textarea type="text" id="tweet" placeholder="What's up?" name="tweet"></textarea>
 <button type="submit">Tweet!</button>
 </form>
```

Whenever I press submit. name and tweets gets saved but I don't know how to save the date.

The .js code is like this:

```
app.post('/tweets', (req, res) => {
db.collection('tweets').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
 if (err) return console.log(err)

console.log('saved to database')
res.redirect('/')
})
})
```

When I used jQuery I had a button like this in index.html:

```
<input type="button" id="addTweet" value="Tweet!"/>
```

where in the .js file did it like this:

```
  $('#addTweet').click(function(){
var addObj = {
  "name": $('#name').val(),
  "date": getTodayDate(),
  "body": $('#tweet').val()
}
```

This way I could save the date when they clicked the button. On Node.js I don't understand how/where I can put the date in.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wouldn't take this data on the front end unless you want the user to be able to manipulate it.  On the back end, however, you can just create a `new Date()` and save it to a field in your database (`created_at` perhaps).

Comment: @snapjs I want the date to be saved the moment user presses "Submit". I have edited the post with code now, and I don't understand where I should send the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential option is to modify your request as you're saving it.  This of course assumes you don't have to make any structural changes to an underlying database.

```
app.post('/tweets', (req, res) => {
  req.body.created_at = new Date();
  db.collection('tweets').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a JavaScript function that runs before submitting the form, but to be honest you're much better off just setting the submit date on the server, since you don't really care what time it is on the clients computer. Your database can probably do it for you with timestamp fields or you can do it in node in your express route.

If you provide more details on how you've built your routes and what database you're using I'll give more details.

Comment: Hi! I edited the post now where I explain what I did before with jQuery. I use mongodb to save the data, but just don't understand where I can send the date with.